# What are the WeTransfer URL parameters to auto fill the From email address input field?

Tags: wetransfer

How would you set a URL parameter to fill in the field for the From email input field?

I have been able to fill in all of the fields minus the from email address input field.

[image]

The to field populates fine with: https://wetransfer.com/?to=email@domain.com
Haven't figured out how to prefill the from email. What is the parameter?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following:

- `to` for the recipient
- `msg` for the message body text
- `title` for the title

`from` or similar does not seem to be supported.

So for example: https://wetransfer.com/?to=test@test.com&title=MyTitle&msg=TestBody

Watch out for URL encoding.